# Run a script/file to open BitPay wallet in one click?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to get a faster way to open the BitPay wallet on Linux (ubuntu).
It requires me to write this every time in the terminal:

```
$ cd Desktop
$ cd BitPay-linux
$ ./BitPay
```

Is there a way to condense this into one script/file that I can run instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an [`alias`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) for this in your `.bashrc`:

```
    alias bp=~/Desktop/BitPay-linux/BitPay
# or
    alias bp="cd ~/Desktop/BitPay-linux && ./BitPay"
```

Once defined, you can simply say `bp` in a terminal window.

Open your `~/.bashrc` in an editor. Most likely there are already some aliases defined, like `alias ll="ls -l"` or something similar. Just add one of the above lines there (or somewhere else) and save the file so it will take effect for all new terminal windows.

I tend to create a new section in my ~/.bashrc with a comment so that all my custom aliases are in one place, like so:

```
...

######################
# My custom aliases
######################
alias ll="ls -l"
alias ..="cd .."
alias bp="cd ~/Desktop/BitPay-linux && ./BitPay"
...
```